# How to maximize the modulus of a multivariate complex-valued function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, maximum

My problem is the following.

I have a messy, complex-valued function

```
 H[L_, G_, l_, g_] = -6.2593722277693634*10^(-9)*(4.303126009293465*10^(-11)* 
   Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 (1/2 + 2.420508380227574*^-11 L^4) Cos[
    l] + (1.058540218602996*10^(-16)* L^6 + 
     2.8468949665960885*10^(-27)* L^10) Cos[g + l] - 
  4.303126009293465*10^(-11)* Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 (9/4 + 5.378907511616831*10^(-11)*L^4) Cos[
    2 g + l] + (3.2273445069700985*10^(-11)* L^4 + 
     5.786529203705594*10^(-22)*L^8) Cos[2 g + 2 l] + 
  3.2273445069700985*10^(-11)* Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 Cos[
    2 g + 3 l] + (1.76423369767166*10^(-16)*L^6 + 
     3.3213774610287704*10^(-27) *L^10) Cos[3 g + 3 l] + 
  1.0126426106484789*10^(-21)* L^8 Cos[4 g + 4 l] + 
  5.978479429851786*10^(-27)* L^10 Cos[5 g + 5 l]) - 8.913267176762544*10^(-10)*(6.798114774925959*10^(-26)*
   L^4 Cos[81.6814089933346 + 2 g + 2 l] + 
  1.2188810209227538*10^(-36)* 
   L^8 Cos[81.6814089933346 + 2 g + 2 l] + 
  2.1330417866148187*10^(-36)* 
   L^8 Cos[163.3628179866692 + 4 g + 4 l] + 
  2.4047395914526166*10^(-12)* Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 (-Sin[l] + Sin[62.83185307179586 + l]) + 
  1.1641384666752184*10^(-22)*Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^8 (-Sin[l] + Sin[62.83185307179586 + l]) + 
  9.100767021362843*10^(-18)*
   L^6 (Sin[g + l] - Sin[81.6814089933346 + g + l]) + 
  2.447609204634166*10^(-28)* 
   L^10 (Sin[g + l] - Sin[81.6814089933346 + g + l]) + 
  5.055981678534912*10^(-18)* 
   L^6 (Sin[3 (g + l)] - Sin[3 (81.6814089933346 + g + l)]) + 
  9.518480240243979*10^(-29)*
   L^10 (Sin[3 (g + l)] - Sin[3 (81.6814089933346 + g + l)]) + 
  1.0279958659463498*10^(-28)*
   L^10 (Sin[5 (g + l)] - Sin[5 (81.6814089933346 + g + l)]) + 
  6.763330100960487*10^(-12)* Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 (-Sin[2 g + l] + Sin[100.53096491487335 + 2 g + l]) + 
  1.6168589814933596*10^(-22)*Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^8 (-Sin[2 g + l] + Sin[100.53096491487335 + 2 g + l]) - 
  1.0019748297719237*10^(-12)* Sqrt[1 - G^2/L^2]
    L^4 (-Sin[2 g + 3 l] + Sin[226.19467105846508 + 2 g + 3 l]));
```

in four variables defined on a complex domain, `Dom` which is the cartesian product of

- Two complex balls `Ball[La,rL]` and `Ball[Ga,rG]` to which `L` and `G` belong respectively.
- Two open complex sets `Reg1` and `Reg2` to which `l` and `g` belong respectively.

I am trying to maximize the modulus of `H` with `(L, G, l, g)` varying over `Dom`.

The problems I have are

1. I don't know how to compute the cartesian product of the sets `Ball[La, rL]`, `Ball[Ga, rG]`, `Reg1` and `Reg1`.
2. I would like to have an expression of the kind

   ```
   Maximize[H, {L, G, l, g} ∈ Dom]
   ```

but I don't know if this is the right way to proceed.

Basically, I need to maximize the modulus of a complex-valued function of many complex variables on a specific domain and I have no idea of how to do that.

Comment: Never use upper-case letters for functions as these will conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal function names.  For example `D` is the derivative operator and your code will never run in its present, un-syntactic form.

Comment: If this a question about the *Mathematica* software, please formulate it as expressions interpretable by *Mathematica*, and show us what you've tried as a solution. If not, you are asking the wrong group.

Comment: I've edited my post. Sorry for not being clear, it's my first time asking a question here.

Comment: None of this makes any sense in *Mathematica* context. For example, `Disk` is a graphical object, not a set. Can you formulate this as a *Mathematica* problem?

Comment: Re-edited :) Hope it's more clear now. Just take the expression for the function H; I have no clue on how to maximize its modulus on its domain (which is the cartesian product of four complex sets).

Comment: Perhaps you should try expressing the domain as algebraic inequalities, and study the documentation for `NMaximize` and its relatives.